# How do I hide all columns except for ones that contain a certain specific value/text?

Tags: excel, hide, display

What's a VBA macro I can use to filter out the columns that don't contain a certain string of text/value. In the example below, I start off with data that has some columns I don't want to see. I want to hide all columns except for ones containing at least one cell that has value I want to see, in this example, it's the "Good" data.

Starting with this:

[image: Excel spreadsheet image showing four columns containing either cells with either "Bad" or "Good" with one column having only "Bad"]

Ending with this:

[image: Excel spreadsheet image showing three columns containing cells with both "Bad" or "Good"]

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you!  I added the code I figured out down below.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code, repeating for every column there could possibly be data I want to see. This assumes the possibly important data is in row 4. Is there a more efficient way?

```
If Range("A4").Value = "important" Then
    Columns("A").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("B4").Value = "important" Then
    Columns("B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("C4").Value = "important" Then
    Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("D4").Value = "important" Then
    Columns("D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("E4").Value = "important" Then
    Columns("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("F4").Value = "important" Then
    Columns("F").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("G4").Value = "important" Then
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("H4").Value = "important" Then
    Columns("H").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("I4").Value = "important" Then
    Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("J4").Value = "important" Then
    Columns("BJ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
```